# Some simple system calls take milliseconds

Tags: linux, debian, system-calls

I'm running a small number of game servers (one per cpu core). However despite that the hardware is quite powerful and no other tasks are running on those cores, I'm constantly facing some problems related to the stability of frames per second indicator. Something causes game server processes to be waiting for too long (sometimes up to 3-4 ms, which is unacceptable in my case).

Strace utility shows something like:

```
17:56:27.683580 gettimeofday({1374414987, 683587}, NULL) = 0 <0.000003>
17:56:27.683599 gettimeofday({1374414987, 683606}, NULL) = 0 <0.000003>
17:56:27.683619 gettimeofday({1374414987, 683626}, NULL) = 0 <0.001693>
17:56:27.685387 gettimeofday({1374414987, 685437}, NULL) = 0 <0.000034>
17:56:27.685492 gettimeofday({1374414987, 685550}, NULL) = 0 <0.000025>
```

Perhaps it is the reason why those lags (taking into account that the gameserver process is single-threaded) happen.

However, the question is why do some of system calls take so much time? I've tried kernels with various types of kernel preemtion, but the result is still the same.

Looking forward for your help.

P.S.

OS - Debian 7 64 bit
Linux kernel version - 3.2.46

Comment: Maybe you had a context-switch during the call.

Comment: Servers are running with real time priority. I even tried to isolate some of cpu cores, but it was still the same thing.

Comment: Try using the `getrusage` system call and checking the `ru_nvcsw` and `ru_nivcsw`.  That way you can at least determine if it is a context switch or something else.

Comment: one of the first things i learned when starting to do audio realtime programming, was to never ever use system calls in the realtime process. instead use a separate thread.